# How can I integrate a react app into a static HTML website

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to build a checkout form with react, that will contain a lot of dynamic components. I know how to create a react app but I don't know if it's possible to add a small react-app into different html webpages of a website - or many small apps into these pages

So that would give us the **checkoutFormApp** :

- not added to index.html
- added to myWonderfulProduct.html
- added to myWonderfulProduct2.html
- not added to /blog/*

And than my second app **memberAccess** :

- not added to index.html
- added to members/index.html

etc.

I'm currently using Jerkyll to build the static website, so I'm also wondering where to put the react-App so I can develop it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Every React app have an entry point: the `render` method of the `react-dom` module (in this case you're using the web version).

In that method you have to provide the root component of the app, *and* the HTML node where you want to place your app in the DOM tree.
Usually that nodes are called something like `#root`, `#app`, or something else that states clearly that there is where your app is stored.

However, you can pass any DOM node, so you can have your HTML with all the other stuff, and another DOM element that you can identify somehow where your react app can be loaded.

Comment: This is kind of clear to me, the question I'm lost with is how to integrate both. So you create a folder out of the html root, with your app1, and than in the app1 have a <div id="app1div"> and than integrate to that id from the app. That's ok, what I'm lost with is, how to connect my app with my web page.